# Unskewing child divs of parent div

Tags: html, css

I have a parent element skewed to make a parallelogram. I cannot seem to figure out how to unskew the child elements, I even browsed through multiple old Stack questions and found solutions, but it is not working for me.

Here is the link to the CodePen:
http://codepen.io/DerekDev/pen/MYQrrQ

I am using this to skew:

```
  -webkit-transform: skew(20deg, 0deg);
  -moz-transform: skew(20deg, 0deg);
  -ms-transform: skew(20deg, 0deg);
  -o-transform: skew(20deg, 0deg);
  transform: skew(20deg, 0deg);
```

And this to unskew the child, but like I said, it is not working:

```
  -webkit-transform: skew(-20deg, 0deg) !important;
  -moz-transform: skew(-20deg, 0deg) !important;
  -ms-transform: skew(-20deg, 0deg) !important;
  -o-transform: skew(-20deg, 0deg) !important;
  transform: skew(-20deg, 0deg) !important;
```

If anyone has any solution that could fix this, that would be great.

P.S. I need it in pure css :)

Comment: You have a typo in the selector (`.bar status {..}`). You are missing a `.` before status.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I know the issue. It was just a simple typo in the code, I forgot to add a dot in the CSS.

Comment: Well, share the issue?

Comment: @JoshHarington Sure thing - it was just a simple typo in the code, I forgot to add a dot in the css...

Answer (score 0):

Just add a `.` before `status` so you can select `class="status"` instead of `<status>`